# Can badges be “automated”?

Tags: discussion, badges, ethics

It seems to me that badges like “fanatic” can be automated, i.e. someone could put a script together to “earn” that badge.  Is there any safeguard against such practice?  Or is it regarded as fair-play (as in “if you even managed to put such a script together, dude, you deserve it”?!

Comment: You _don't_ earn fanatic just by visiting the site every day. It's a bit more complicated than that. But if you did go through the trouble of writing a script to earn a silly badge, then I'd say you deserve to call yourself fanatic...

Comment: Since 90% of the users above 3k rep are AI software written by Jon Skeet, I'd say that yes - one can automate getting badges.

Answer (score 22):

Most bot automation is successfully thwarted by Captcha's.

In the case of Fanatic, if someone really wants to go to all the trouble to write a script, and then wait the 100 days it takes for that script to hit the site once each day to obtain the badge, I'd say they deserve it.

Comment: That would yield the "Automatic Fanatic" badge :)

Comment: @Jack I would love to see more rhyming badges :)

Answer (score 19):

I think you're asking the wrong question here. While cheating to obtain badges may violate the spirit of gathering them, no one really cares what you do to get a badge. It's *just* a badge after all. Badges don't give you reputation, and they don't gain you additional privileges throughout the site.

**However**, certain badges which involve behavior which may be considered destructive to the site and other users **is** a problem. Automating votes or reviews, for instance, is a very destructive behavior that can cause the quality of the site to decrease. Actions such as these will result in a lengthy suspension.

- Writing a script to get yourself the Fanatic badge - whatever, go for it, we really couldn't care less.
- Writing a script to get the Publicist badge - you're starting to push the line. While not causing *too much* harm, you would be making a question appear more popular and accessible to other visitors than it actually is in reality.
- Writing a script to reach your 300 votes for Civic Duty - we have a problem here. While you're free to vote how you please, an automated process certainly isn't voting based on the content. That would be similar to voting based on a user, which is definitely discouraged.
- Writing a script to automatically edit posts to get to Copy Editor - you can probably expect a suspension shortly after.

So any consequences you encounter would be a result of the actions you are taking in order to gain a badge and how harmful they are to our site as a whole. Visiting the site is completely harmless, so why would we have a problem with that, even if it does give you a badge?

Comment: +1 It seems that scripting the Publicist badge is already [crossing the line](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130135/169611).

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that there are rules around this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can technically be automated.

But only the SO devs know the **Exact** way to get the badge (actions taken etc)

So your script could be useless and a waste of time :-P